# sbt supress ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m

Tags: sbt

```
PS D:\Users\erick\repos\leaderboard> sbt about

The Java Development Kit (JDK) installation you have is not up to date.
sbt requires at least version 6+, you have
version 0

Please go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ and download
a valid JDK and install before running sbt.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from D:\Users\erick\repos\leaderboard\project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to leaderboard (in build file:/D:/Users/erick/repos/leaderboard/)
[info] This is sbt 1.1.4
[info] The current project is ProjectRef(uri("file:/D:/Users/erick/repos/leaderboard/"), "leaderboard") 0.0.0
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.12.5
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, sbt.plugins.Giter8TemplatePlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.12.4
```

Been searching for almost an hour for some way to suppress

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

in SBT, but it seems impossible. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

As usual, I seem to find the solutions shortly after posting the problem:

1. Go to SBT installation directory
2. edit conf/sbtconfig.txt
3. remove `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Sadly, Google provides many sbt hits that are either wrong or out of date, so it takes a while to find valid solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This Solution worked for me

1. Go to project directory
2. Open directory **sbt-dist\conf**
3. Open **sbtconfig.txt** file and comment below property by putting # prior the line
   **#-XX:MaxPermSize=256m**

There are many solution which show downgrade to java version. You don't need to do just follow above steps . It will work.